# How do I implement encrypted peer-to-peer chat in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, encryption, p2p

I'm interested in making an in-company encrypted peer-to-peer chat app in Cocoa, but I don't even know where to start.

Can you point me in the right direction? What books, documentation, etc. do you recommend? I need to learn about peer-to-peer and encryption.

I know Objective-C and Cocoa, but I am completely clueless about peer-to-peer and encryption.

Comment: Just a thought. Why do you need to roll your own? iChat is encrytable ,as is MS Communicator or Skype(and many others) Just curious as to why you would spend a lot more on dev time than you would on off the shelf.

Comment: Good question. Maybe I'm paranoid. It's true that Skype is encrypted. But the stuff still goes through their servers, and thus in theory can be intercepted by Skype when the message is in their own server.

Comment: The second reason is that maybe it's just a good learning opportunity for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked on a project with very similar design goals a few years ago, albeit written in Java, called [Spaghetti Nodes](https://github.com/mdippery/snodes). It was more focused as a file-sharing app, but also included a chat component. The project has since stalled, but there are a few notes on the [wiki](https://github.com/mdippery/snodes/wiki) that you may find helpful. I also wrote a post-mortem [blog post](http://www.monkey-robot.com/blog/2008/03/13/spaghetti-nodes/) about the experience.

This question is pretty broad, but here a few pointers to get started:

- Consider using Bonjour for the peer-to-peer connectivity, if possible. (Peer-to-peer only works on local networks and doesn't work well, if at all, across subnets, so this may not be a possibility.)
- You'll probably want to use an SSH-like method for encryption. That is, users have private/public key pairs, and distribute the public keys. You use the key pair to initiate a session, then negotiate a one-time encryption key so you can use faster symmetric key encryption for the rest of the session.
- We used the Twofish algorithm for symmetric encryption.

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion, as a good starting point as any (although it's a lot more general than P2P/encryption) would probably be the [Bonjour Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000119i) docs as such a service would provide a nice means of broadcasting/listening to see who's currently on the chat system.

There's also some sample code associated with the [NSNetService class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetService_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs that might prove very useful and at least provide some good pointers as to where to look next.